# copy SVN modified files only to another directory

Tags: svn, unix, version-control, ack

I have a list of files in my current working copy that have been modified locally. There are about 50 files that have been changed.

I can get a list of these files by doing this:

```
svn st | ack '^M'
```

Is there a way I can copy these files and *only* these files to another directory, which is called `backup`?

Comment: please edit your post to show a small sample of the output produced by your svn pipeline. Then we can easily help. Its likely that you can do it as a 1-liner. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming ack is like grep... you could do something like:

```
cp `svn st | ack '^M' | cut -b 8-` backup
```

I'd post this as a comment... but I don't know how to escape the backticks in comments...

Comment: Is it possible to do this and _maintain_ the directories that the files are in? For example, if a modified file is in `/images` then can I create/copy an `/images` folder when copying the files to the `/backup` directory?

Comment: For some reason on mac above command didnt work. I used following svn status | grep '^[ADMR]' | cut -b 8- | xargs -I '{}' cp  {} /directory/

Comment: @forsvarir: backticks (at least in bash) can be exchanged by $()-constructs (which btw allows for nested expressions). I solved the "maintain the directories" issue: `for i in $(svn st|grep ^[MA]|cut -b 8-); do x="b/$(dirname $i)";mkdir -p $x;cp "$i" "$x";done`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I use the awesome bash script of @JoergReinhardt To include **unscheduled files/directories** in the backup and avoid problems with **nested directories**, I modified the script: `for i in $(svn st|grep ^[MA?]|cut -b 8-); do x="../_svnexport/$(dirname $i)";mkdir -p $x;cp -ir "$i" "$x";done`.
_svn st|grep ^[MA?]|cut -b 8-_: Get modified, added and unscheduled files/directories path.
_mkdir -p_: Create parent directories if not available.
_cp -ir "$i"_: Copy files/dirs recursively and ask what to do if file/directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn status | grep '^[ADMR]' | cut -b 8- | xargs -I '{}' rsync -R  {} /directry/
```

Comment: I've just tried this out, but it doesn't maintain the directories the files are in. So if you have a /inc/picco.txt then it doesn't create the `inc/`.

Comment: rsync -R should preserve the directory structure. I have updated the script. please let me know if this is working for you .

Answer (score 1):

This would do (bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# for each modified file
for f in $(svn st| awk '/^M/{print $2}'); do
    # create a directory under backup root and copy the file there
    mkdir -p .../backup/${f%/*} && cp -a $f .../backup/$f
done
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run that code. Apologies,  i'm not familiar with bash scripting. `copy_modified_files.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching )'`

Comment: @crmpicco - was missing parenthesis before '; do'

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8, can use this command in current svn directory:

```
(FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== " %i IN ('svn st ^| findstr "^[ADMR]"') DO @echo %i & echo f| xcopy /f /y %i c:\projects\backup\%i)
```

Comment: tried to run this but it has some bug with directories

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
svn status | grep ^M | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I '{}' cp --parents {} /backup/
```